# How to connect to Amazon Simple AD using ldaps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ldap, amazon-directory-services

I cannot seem to connect to Amazon Simple AD using an ldaps:// url (with the default port number 636). I am getting "Connection refused".

It works with the non-encrypted ldap:// (port 389).

Is there something I need to enable on the AD or VPC or Security Groups settings?

---

Motivation: I suppose plain LDAP may be secure enough, as it is going via VPC anyway, but the software attached to it (WSO2 Identity Server) seems to insist on LDAPS:

> WARN {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} -  Connection to the Active Directory is not secure. Passowrd involved operations such as update credentials and adduser operations will fail

Comment: I have not tried this myself but perhaps you can use http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#Translucent%20Proxy to proxy from ldaps to ldap if you really need the operations listed above. This looked promising too: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alextch/archive/2012/04/25/configuring-openldap-pass-through-authentication-to-active-directory.aspx

Comment: Where on earth are you finding the URL, or even the IP for the server. I also created a Simple AD deployment but the instances are not showing in EC2. Obviously its servers you can't manage like that ... but now I have know way to use the directory since I can't access it.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to work around the issue by launching a local `stunnel` that accepts LDAPS and just pipes it out again as LDAP to Simple AD.

Configuration looks something like this

```
# Service-level configuration
[ldap]
accept  = 8636
connect = SimpleAD_IP:389
```

Comment: how did this work? When ldaps piped to ldap, did Simple AD take it as ldaps and accept the password set up?

Comment: @tarikakyol: No, Simple AD would just see regular LDAP. So there is no security benefit (the connection to Simple AD is not encrypted), this was just useful to make it work at all.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Amazon does not enable ldaps at all, these are the only ports mentioned which have to be open and ldap over ssl is not amongst them (neither for the normal or the global catalog):

- ...
- TCP/UDP 389 - LDAP
- TCP 3268 - Global Catalog
- ...

(values taken from the [admin guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/cloud_prereq.html))

In a comment published on a Amazon [blog](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx3J2RL8V6N72G7/Using-LDAP-via-AWS-Directory-Service-to-Access-and-Administer-Your-Hadoop-Enviro) it is stated that

> LDAPs is not currently supported with AWS Directory Service at this
>   time.

Answer (score 0):

As an update LDAPS seems to work now out of the box with Simple AD, Enterprise Microsoft AD does not have LDAPS out of the box though

Comment: Do you have any source for ldaps support on AWS Simple AD? The official link *still* says no ldaps support - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/prereq_simple.html

"TCP/UDP 389 - LDAP; note that AWS Directory Service does not support LDAP with SSL (LDAPS) or LDAP signing"

Comment: It may be an undocumented feature. I just tried it  out and saw that it worked with SSL on 636.

Answer (score 0):

AWS expects you to use a proxy for SSL termination. You could use something like HAProxy. If you want to have it available to the public webs then you would use something like ELB with a cert. Here is the documentation:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-configure-an-ldaps-endpoint-for-simple-ad/